# git: Invalid username or password even tough no credential manager or credentials in Wincred

Tags: git, git-for-windows, credential-manager

Since  my last token for github authentication expired, git on windows prompt me that the username and password are invalid (Which is correct)

Only problem is, whatever I do, I cannot reset, change or remove them. I tried changing them in Credential Manager (**Control Pannel** > **Credential Manager**) I tried removing all entries corresponding to git or github, tried removing the credential helper (`git config --unset credential.helper`) on all level (`--global`, `--local`, etc.) But still nothing work.

The only way I can possibly push or pull changes at the moment is by using the git commands trough WSL2, which does prompt me for user and password(token that I have to either save somewhere or create a new one each time from GH)

I am out of idea and I cannot seem to find any other lead for a solution.

Comment: Have you tried looking if you have a file at C:\Users\<username>\.git-credentials ?

Comment: I don't have any files named `.git-credentials` but I did find in `.gitconfig` a parameter `[url "https://<git-username>:<old_gh_token>@github.com"]
 insteadOf = https://github.com`. Once I removed that line, everything worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @SOROMEED comment, I was able to find the a new solution.

git config file, located in `C:\Users\<username>\.gitconfig` had the following block:

```
[url "https://<gh_username>:<old_gh_token>@github.com"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com
```

Removing that line, forced git to prompt for my credentials againt

Note: the `gh_username` was also incorrect since I changed it a couple month ago but was not changed in this file.

Comment: Good! It is strange though that your git config commands did not have effect on this file...